# Compare Swift String and NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, equality

How can I compare a NSAttributedString and a Swift String such that:

```
let string = "test string"
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string)
let areStringsEqual = attributedString == string
```

will compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways:

**First**

Change

```
attributedString == string
```

to

```
attributedString.string == string
```

**Second**

Add this to your code:

```
//for attributed.string == string
func ==(lhs: NSAttributedString, rhs: String) -> Bool {
    return lhs.string == rhs
}

//for string == attributed.string
func ==(lhs: String, rhs: NSAttributedString) -> Bool {
    return lhs = rhs.string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an answer using an extension of NSAttributedString utilizing an equality operator:

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    static func ==(lhs: NSAttributedString, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        return lhs.string == rhs
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `lhs.string == rhs`?

Comment: There's really no need for this method. Simply do: `let areStringsEqual = attributedString.string == string`. Even if you want this extra `==` function, there is no need to create the mutable attributed string.

Comment: kkkk Why are you using mutable if you are not mutating anything and you are interested only in its string property?

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice NSAttributedString has a `string` property. Updated the answer to remove NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Why don't you create an instance method to match the one that exists for attributed string also ?    `func isEqual(to string: String) -> Bool {
            return self.string == string
    }`